# How to change spectrogram's x-axis ticks?

Tags: matlab, plot, spectrogram

Say, I have an example signal, which is a simple 1x1001 array. I had plotted it on the normal, line plot, beside of its spectrogram (see below). Now, as you can see, x-axis of the line plot is expressed in respect to the signal length. How can I share this x-axis with the spectrogram? Unfortunetaly, the solution proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676100/set-the-same-ticks-range-for-each-subplots-x-axis is not working, and the person, who gave me the answer advice me to create a new, specific topic.

Anyway, here is my code with working example:

```
t = 0:0.001:1; % time in milliseconds
f0 = 100;
f1 = 400;               
signal = chirp(t, f0, 1, f1, 'q', [], 'convex');

frequencies = 0:.1:500;
window = 256;
NFFT = 255;

figure;
p1 = subplot(2, 1, 1);
spectrogram(signal, window, NFFT, frequencies, 1E3, 'yaxis'); 
axis xy; axis tight; colormap(jet); view(0,90);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)');

p2 = subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(signal);
xlabel('Time (ms)');
ylabel('Amplitude (uV)');
```

[image]

The spectrogram's x-axis ticks should span from 0 to 1000.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution involving `XTickLabel` ( to insert after your first subplot):

```
Xlim = get(gca, 'xlim');
set(gca, 'XTick', linspace(Xlim(1), Xlim(2), 7);
set(gca, 'XTicklabel', 0:100:1200);
```

Best